# How to filter search results by path using Algolia?

Tags: gatsby, netlify, algolia, instantsearch

I have a website built with Gatsby, published with Netlify, that uses Algolia crawler and InstantSearch to help users find help articles more easily. How can I limit the results so it only shows pages that start with `/help/` ?

For example, if I search for “xyz”, I get the following results:

```
/
/help
/blog/xyz
/help/xyz
/help/xyzabc
...
```

I need to filter results so that only the last ones, `/help/xyz` and `/help/xyzabc`, are shown.

What’s the best way of handling this? In Netlify, in the crawler, Algolia dashboard, InstantSearch?

I would really appreciate guidance with this.